# Поддержка русских символов в error.log (Apache 2.4)

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

Возможно ли как-то заставить Apache 2.4 писать лог ошибок на русском языке?

У меня они пишутся так:

```
ORA-20001: \xd0\x9d\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9 \xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbf
```

Различными конвертерами, естественно, все конвертируется в русский текст, но хотелось бы видеть русский язык в логе.

Comment: А какая ОС? И откуда приходят русские символы?

Comment: ОС, на которой установлен apache - Windows Server 2012. Русские символы приходят из php 7

Comment: скорей всего проблема в кодировке. php видимо передает в unicode, а apache ожидает 1251.